# SharedPreferences manager can't write nor read preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have created a classe called "reglages" (settings in english) that should be able to save preferences from any kind of activities. But it's seems that it can't save nor return data from sharedPreferences :

Reglages.java

```
public class Reglages {

    // Compte utilisateur
    public static final String PREFERENCES_COMPTE_UTILISATEUR = "[compte_utilisateur]";
    private static final String COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_NOM = "nom";
    private static final String COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_PRENOM = "prenom";
    private static final String COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_FONCTION = "fonction";
    private static final String COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_TEL = "tel";
    private static final String COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_PASSWORD = "mot_de_passe";


    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    public Reglages(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Met les preferences a Compte Utilisateur
     */
    private void setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur() {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_COMPTE_UTILISATEUR, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = preferences.edit();
    }

    /* COMPTE UTILISATEURS METHODES  */

    /**
     * Ajouter ou mettre a jour le nom du compte utilisateur
     * @param nom
     */
    public void compteUtilisateurSetNom(String nom) {
        setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur();
        editor.putString(COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_NOM, nom);
        editor.commit();
        Log.i("compteUtilisateur", "Nom = " + nom);
    }
    /**
     * Retourne le nom du compte utilisateur
     * @return
     */
    public String compteUtilisateurGetNom() {
        setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur();
        String nom = preferences.getString(COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_NOM, "0");
        return nom;
    }
    /**
     * Ajouter ou mettre a jour le prenom du compte utilisateur
     * @param prenom
     */
    public void compteUtilisateurSetPrenom(String prenom) {
        setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur();
        editor.putString(COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_NOM, prenom);
        editor.commit();
        Log.i("compteUtilisateur", "Prenom = " + prenom);
    }
    /**
     * Retourne le prenom du compte utilisateur
     * @return
     */
    public String compteUtilisateurGetPrenom() {
        setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur();
        return preferences.getString(COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_PRENOM, "");
    }
    /**
     * Ajouter ou mettre a jour la fonction du compte utilisateur
     * @param fonction
     */
    public void compteUtilisateurSetFonction(String fonction) {
        setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur();
        editor.putString(COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_NOM, fonction);
        editor.commit();
        Log.i("compteUtilisateur", "Fonction = " + fonction);
    }
    /**
     * Retourne la fonction du compte utilisateur
     * @return
     */
    public String compteUtilisateurGetFonction() {
        setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur();
        return preferences.getString(COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_FONCTION, "");
    }
    /**
     * Ajouter ou mettre a jour le numero de telephone du compte utilisateur
     * @param tel
     */
    public void compteUtilisateurSetTel(String tel) {
        setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur();
        editor.putString(COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_TEL, tel);
        editor.commit();
        Log.i("compteUtilisateur", "Tel = " + tel);
    }
    /**
     * Retourne le numero de telephone du compte utilisateur
     * @return
     */
    public String compteUtilisateurGetTel() {
        setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur();
        return preferences.getString(COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_TEL, "");
    }
    /**
     * Ajouter ou mettre a jour le mail du compte utilisateur
     * @param email
     */
    public void compteUtilisateurSetEmail(String email) {
        setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur();
        editor.putString(COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_EMAIL, email);
        editor.commit();
        Log.i("compteUtilisateur", "Email = " + email);
    }
    /**
     * Retourne le mail du compte utilisateur
     * @return
     */
    public String compteUtilisateurGetEmail() {
        setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur();
        return preferences.getString(COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_EMAIL, "");
    }
    /**
     * Ajouter ou mettre a jour le mot de passe du compte utilisateur
     * @param password
     */
    public void compteUtilisateurSetPassword(String password) {
        setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur();
        editor.putString(COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_PASSWORD, password);
        editor.commit();
        Log.i("compteUtilisateur", "Mot de passe = " + password);
    }
    /**
     * Retourne le mot de passe du compte utilisateur
     * @return
     */
    public String compteUtilisateurGetPassword() {
        setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur();
        return preferences.getString(COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_PASSWORD, "");
    }
}
```

So in the others classes i should just do something like this to use it :
To insert data :

```
Reglages reglages = new Reglages(context);
reglages.compteUtilisateurSetNom("test");
```

To retrieve data :

```
Reglages reglages = new Reglages(context);
String test = reglages.compteUtilisateurGetNom();
```

but it display nothing, not even the default value which is "0".

Comment: may be you are using different context from differnt class. you can use it as singleton

Comment: You aren't calling `commit` on your `Editor`

Comment: The context is passed with getContextApplication() it worked with everything else.

Comment: @codeMagic he calls inside compteUtilisateurSetNom

Comment: what does "not even the default value which is 0" mean? Why you need your reglages class to be instantiable?

Comment: I tested a toast and it display nothing, not even the default value "0", and i want to centralize all my data into a single class.

Comment: instead of toast could you put a Log inside compteUtilisateurGetNom. Still a class with all static method should be suffice (I use this way. Why do you need to create everytime a new Reglages ? )

Comment: not everytime, it's just to access it more easily

Comment: more easly then  the static way ? If your method are static you should call directly as Reglages.compteUtilisateurGetNom() for instance

Comment: But how can you get the context ? Is it a singleton ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30885/discussion-between-blackbelt-and-tsunaze)

Comment: `public static String getLoginInfo(Context context, String key) {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
    Costants.SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
  String username = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
 
  
  return username;
 }`

Comment: still it should work in your way. Maybe something is wrong with the internal memory? Have tried to uninstall and reinstall the application? Do you have space in the internal memory

Comment: I would see the snippeto of code where you show the string returned by compteUtilisateurGetNom()

Comment: I really think it was the name of the preference, because when i create a preference, there is an xml being generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static final String PREFERENCES_COMPTE_UTILISATEUR = "[compte_utilisateur]";
```

If this is the filename, that may be a problem. Access the shell and see if the file is even being created. Those brackets need to be escaped I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

There is something I don't understand in your code, why not changing this part:

```
public Reglages(Context context) {
this.context = context;
}

private void setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur() {
preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_COMPTE_UTILISATEUR, PRIVATE_MODE);
editor = preferences.edit();
}
```

With this to avoid your repetitions:

```
public Reglages(Context context) {
    this.preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_COMPTE_UTILISATEUR, Context.PRIVATE_MODE);
    this.editor = preferences.edit();
}
```

I also added the `this`, in case your problem comes from that. This is the code I am using on my own app, you can give it a try.

Comment: because i will add more preferences in the same page, different ones.

Comment: Why not creating a different class? For a different kind of preferences?

Comment: i've got something like 9 on them.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur()` as described in the following code:

```
private void setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur(boolean write) {
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_COMPTE_UTILISATEUR, PRIVATE_MODE);

    //If we are going to write a preference, we set the write variable true.
    if(write) {
        editor = preferences.edit();
    }
}
```

This way when you read a preference you need to call the above method as in the following example:

```
public String compteUtilisateurGetEmail(){
    setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur(false); //We only need to read, not write
    return preferences.getString(COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_EMAIL, "");
}
```

And in the same principle when you call a write preference method you do it as following:

```
public void compteUtilisateurSetPassword(String password){
    setPreferencesCompteUtilisateur(true);
    editor.putString(COMPTE_UTILISATEUR_PASSWORD, password);
    editor.commit();
    Log.i("compteUtilisateur", "Mot de passe = "+password);
}
```

I suspect the problem is that when you read a shared preference, you always call `preferences.edit();` as your code is right now.